# Open a modal by clicking on a background <img>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, modal-dialog

i have a button that open a modal, the button is on a background image, i have to make the photo act as the button.

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="cih1" class="cuadro_intro_hover">
        <img class="lazy" data-original="img/products/001.jpg" alt="">
    <div id="cihc1" class="caption">
        <div id="cihb1" class="blur">
        </div>
        <div class="caption-text">
            <img class="" src="img/maieu.png" alt="" style="width: 114px; height: 140;">
            <h3>Golden Fish</h3>
            <p>Price: 100Lei</p>
            <a href="#Modal1" class="btn btn-primary portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal"><span>Info</span></a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

...and this is the button that open the modal:

```
<a href="#Modal1" class="btn btn-primary portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal"><span>Info</span></a>
```

I have to make  act like  but without the hand mouse cursor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, this should do the trick:

```
$('img').on(
    'click',
    function () {
        $('.portfolio-link').click();
    }
)
```

You probably should add some special class or id to the img tag.

Comment: Actually not really, i have to add `href="#Modal1"` which probably works in the `alt=""` of the `<img>` but i have to also add somehow `data-toggle="modal"` and i have no idea how to do this. `<img class="lazy portfolio-link" data-original="img/products/001.jpg" alt="#Modal1" data-toggle="modal">` didnt work, i have probably done something wrong.

Comment: @EPurpl3, you really should clarify your question. Looks like I'm not only one, who can't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It should be formatted like this (since it's not really a link)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal1">
  Info
</button>
```

Or you could wrap the whole area.

```
<div id="cih1" class="cuadro_intro_hover" data-target="#Modal1">
        <img class="lazy" data-original="img/products/001.jpg" alt="">
    <div id="cihc1" class="caption">
        <div id="cihb1" class="blur">
        </div>
        <div class="caption-text">
            <img class="" src="img/maieu.png" alt="" style="width: 114px; height: 140;">
            <h3>Golden Fish</h3>
            <p>Price: 100Lei</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary portfolio-link"><span>Info</span></a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

It's hard to answer this specifically and exactly without seeing your modal code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear (I have to make act like but without the hand mouse cursor?), but why do you not just include the image inside the modal link? Plus, you need to use data-target="#Modal1", not in the href.

```
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary portfolio-link" data-target="#Modal1" data-toggle="modal">
 <img class="" src="img/maieu.png" alt="" style="width: 114px; height: 140;"></a>
```